# Functions in C counting an array of characters

Tags: c

I am trying to write a small program where I basically count the string length in a function but for some reason it is not outputting anything to the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int search (char* string, char* substring){
    int length = 0;
    while(substring){
        substring++;
        length++;
    }
    return length;

}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char string1[] = "hello world";
    char* string = string1;
    char substring1[] = "world";
    char* substring = substring1;

    int a = search(string,substring);

    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dereference it or you'll keep looping since there's no obvious way for `substring` to become 0.

```
while (*substring)
       ^
```

That's because you're not looking for the `NULL` pointer but rather for the NUL (`\0`) character.

Comment: So simple yet so vital. Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 2):

`substring` is a pointer, as long as it's pointing to somewhere memory, it will never be null (false).

Replace `while(substring)` with `while(*substring)` to look for the `\0` character instead.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of "string" in the search function? You're using the substring variable, but not the string variable.